# Curry Howard correspondence to Predicate Logic?

Tags: type-theory, curry-howard, haskell

So I'm trying to get my head round Curry-Howard. (I've tried at it several times, it's just not gelling/seems too abstract). To tackle something concrete, I'm working through the couple of Haskell tutorials linked from wikipedia, esp [Tim Newsham's](http://www.thenewsh.com/~newsham/formal/curryhoward/). There's also a [useful discussion](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2007-October/thread.html) when Newsham posted the tutorial.

(But I'm going to ignore Newsham's and Piponi's `data` wrappers, and talk about the underlying types.) We have Hilbert's axiom scheme (expressed as **S**, **K** combinators); we have propositions as types; implication as function-arrow; and Modus Ponens as function application:

```
axK :: p -> q -> p
axK  = const
axS :: (p -> q -> r) -> (p -> q) -> p -> r
axS     f                g          x  = f x (g x)

modPons = ($);   infixl 0 `modPons`          -- infix Left, cp ($) is Right
```

Then I can derive the identity law:

```
ident     = axS `modPons` axK `modPons` axK  -- (S K K)
-- ident :: p -> p                           -- inferred
```

Having these types as bare typevars merely corresponding to propositions seems rather unimaginative. Can I use more of the type system to actually construct the propositions? I'm thinking:

```
data      IsNat n  = IsNat !n                -- [Note **]

data      Z        = Z
axNatZ ::            IsNat Z
axNatZ             = IsNat Z

data      S n      = S !n
axNatS :: IsNat n -> IsNat (S n)
axNatS   (IsNat n) = IsNat (S n) 

twoIsNat = axNatS `modPons` (axNatS `modPons` axNatZ)
-- ===> IsNat (S (S Z))
```

**[Note **]** I'm using strict constructors, as per the discussion thread, to avoid introducing **_|_**.

Where:

- `IsNat` is a predicate: making a proposition from a term.
- `n` is a variable.
- `S` is a function, making a term from a variable.
- `Z` is a constant (niladic function).

So I seem to have embedded (First-Order) Predicate Logic(?)

I appreciate my types are not very hygienic; I could easily mix up a typevar-as-proposition with a typevar-as-term. Perhaps I should use the `Kind` system to segregate them. OTOH my axioms would have to be spectacularly wrong to get to any conclusion.

I haven't expressed:

- universal quantifier: it's implicit for the free vars;
- existential quant: in effect constants could act as skolemised existentials;
- equality of terms: I've used repeated typevars in implications;
- relations: this seems to work, or is it fuddlement? ...

```
    data          PlusNat n m l  = PlusNat !n !m !l

    axPlusNatZ :: IsNat m       -> PlusNat Z m m
    axPlusNatZ   (IsNat m)       = PlusNat Z m m

    axPlusNatS :: PlusNat n m l -> PlusNat (S n) m (S l)
    axPlusNatS   (PlusNat n m l) = PlusNat (S n) m (S l)

    plus123 = axPlusNatS `modPons`
              (axPlusNatZ `modPons`
               (axNatS `modPons` (axNatS `modPons` axNatZ)) ) 
    -- ===> PlusNat (S Z) (S (S Z)) (S (S (S Z)))
```

Writing the axioms is easy, courtesy of Wadler's *Theorems for Free!*. Writing the proofs is hard work. (I shall drop the `modPons` and just use function application.)

Is this actually achieving a logic. Or is it crazy stuff? Should I stop before I do any more harm to my brain?

You're supposed to need Dependent Types to express FOPL in Curry-Howard. But I don't seem to be doing that(?)

Comment: The issue with your approach is `IsNat` is not making a proposition from a term, it's making a proposition from a *proposition*.

Comment: Thanks @DerekElkins, I guess you mean the argument to `IsNat` is just a type, so must be a proposition. OK, equally `IsNat n` is just a type so must be a proposition. I must be 'on my honour' not to let `n` escape into proposition-land/appear as argument to a logical connective (which is why I talked about type hygiene). Would you be happier if I used Church encoding for Nats? I think I'm just extending λ-calc with constructors at the type level, same as Haskell at the term level(?)

Comment: P.S. perhaps `n` **is** a _proposition_: it's saying 'I am inhabited'. Which is no more than any typevar is saying under CH. `IsNat n` is saying/witnessing: furthermore, the inhabitant of `n` is of a particular 'Kind', aka 'sort' in logic. Then I'm going beyond Simply-typed λ-calc(?)

Comment: I'm considering posting an answer but there are some details I want to work out. In the mean time, note that [System F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F) corresponds to the Second-Order Intuitionistic *Propositional* Logic (SOIPL). The authors of [Lectures on the Curry-Howard Isomorphism](http://disi.unitn.it/~bernardi/RSISE11/Papers/curry-howard.pdf), which I highly recommend and explains SOPL, [show that it is possible to embed first-order intuitionistic predicate logic into SOIPL](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1285765799).

Comment: In order to have first-order logic, you must first explain how in general you intend to represent predicates. What is a predicate on `Int`? The dependent type theory answer is "it is a *type family* indexed by `Int`". What is your answer? (The point is that proceeding from an example is decieving.)

Comment: Also, it seems to me that there is a mix of ideas and Haskell hacking here that is a bit difficult to disentangle. Haskell hacking is fun but it may also obscure Real Math.

Comment: @AndrejBauer absolutely I'm "Haskell hacking" (but not for fun: it's for learning). Because the "Real Math" is too abstract for my brain, as I said. But I'm being real hairshirt with the Haskell: H98 as far as poss, strict data constructors, no typeclasses/instances, no Type Families. To answer your q: I'm saying `IsNat n` is a type of `Kind *`; therefore represents a proposition. `n` can only appear inside a (strict) `data` constr (`IsNat`, `PlusNat`) so is not a proposition. If I made `Z`, `S n` of a different `Kind` (and `IsNat :: Nat -> *`) would you be happier?

Comment: Well, propositions as types through hacking can be a lot of fun. Just go for Agda instead of Haskell. You'll feel right at home.

Comment: I don't think that learning about the Curry-Howard Isomorphism by playing around with arcane programming languages is the right approach. It isn't going to lead to any *true* understanding of the principle.

Comment: @MilesRout learning is a case of horses for courses, I think. By reading up the texts I was getting _no_ understanding ("true" or otherwise). Not sure which programming languages you class as "arcane". I wanted something close to λ-calculus (I've chosen a tight subset of Haskell), and a language I already knew, so I didn't get confused by which bit was C-H vs which bit was language-arcanery. Please volunteer an actual answer if you know a better way. (If some other language, I know Basic, Fortran, BCPL, LISP, Pascal, COBOL, various assemblers, various CLs/scripting -- none seem promising.)

Comment: If you don't understand the texts, then you should learn what you need to understand the texts. Haskell is not one of those things.

Answer (score 3):

To explain why I'm uncomfortable with Newsham's and (especially) Piponi's `data` wrappers ... (This is going to be more question than answer, but perhaps it'll work towards explaining what's wrong with my `IsNat` even though it seems very similar to Newsham.)

[Piponi page 17 on](http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/1/14/TMR-Issue6.pdf) has:

```
data Proposition = Proposition :-> Proposition
                  | Symbol String
                  | False deriving Eq

data Proof = MP Proof Proof
     | Axiom String Proposition deriving Eq
```

I see no types here. Spelling a data constructor `:->` does not make it function arrow; and spelling a data constructor `MP` (for Modus Ponens) does not make it function application. There's a 'smart constructor' operator `(@@)` for `MP`, but that doesn't apply no function: it merely does pattern matching on the `:->` constructor.

Newsham has (I'll start with the Implication section/Modus Ponens):

```
data Prop p = Prop p

data p :=> q = Imp (Prop p -> Prop q)

impInj :: (Prop p -> Prop q) -> Prop (p :=> q)
impInj p2q = Prop (Imp p2q)

impElim :: Prop p -> Prop (p :=> q) -> Prop q
impElim p (Prop (Imp p2q)) = p2q p
```

This looks more like it: we have types, function arrows, function application in `impElim`. The type constructor `Imp` with its injection and elimination rules mirror the proof tree structures in the *Lectures on Curry-Howard isomorphism*. But I'm nervous: why does `Imp` need a type constructor and data constructor? Again, spelling as `:=>` doesn't make that a function arrow. Why all this wrapping and unwrapping `Prop` constructors? Why not plain `Prop (p -> q)`?

So when I look at the 'Conjunction' section (which actually comes first):

```
data p :/\ q = And (Prop p) (Prop q)

andInj :: Prop p -> Prop q -> Prop (p :/\ q)
andInj p q = Prop (And p q)

andElimL :: Prop (p :/\ q) -> Prop p
andElimL (Prop (And p q)) = p

andElimR :: Prop (p :/\ q) -> Prop q
andElimR (Prop (And p q)) = q
```

Those `Elim` functions **don't** use function application. They merely pattern match on the constructors. There's no implicational structure for conjunction: we rely entirely that the 'programmer' has used only the `andInj` rule to build a type `(p :/\ q)`.

So when Newsham gets to the commutativity of conjunction:

```
commuteAnd :: Prop (p :/\ q) -> Prop (q :/\ p)
commuteAnd pq = andInj (andElimR pq) (andElimL pq)
```

And claims

> Notice that our Haskell proof did not contain any reference to the internal structure of the (:/\) data type. Having defined and proven our rules "andInj", "andElimR" and "andElimL" we shouldn't ever have to peek into the implementation of the (:/\) data type again.

I plain disagree:

- The signature for `commuteAnd` **does** rely on the internal structure of the `:/\` type constructor.
- Although the function definition looks like merely function application, in fact the `andElim`s **do** "peek" into the structure.

I'd expect we could prove the commutativity of conjunction from its definition, without needing an axiom to say so(?)

OK if I'm being so purist, what do I expect? This for conjunction is based on the Church encoding for pair:

```
type Conj p q r = Prop ((p -> q -> r) -> r)     -- not right, see later

andInj :: Prop p -> Prop q -> Conj p q r
andInj (Prop p) (Prop q) = Prop (\elim -> elim p q)

andElimL :: Conj p q p -> Prop p
andElimL (Prop conj) = Prop (conj axK)    -- axK is `const`
```

Now I can write `commuteAnd` using 'proper' function application:

```
--  commuteAnd :: (Conj p q r) -> (Conj q p r)
commuteAnd pq = andInj (andElimR pq) (andElimL pq)
```

That function definition is the same as Newsham's. But I've commented out the signature because GHC's inferred type is not general enough. It wants `Prop ((p -> p -> p) -> p) -> ((p -> p -> p) -> p)`. Which is only a fancy variation on the Identity law.

**Edit:** (After @DerekElkins first comment here.) Scrap all this:

> I've ended up in deep (and murky) water. I think my type for `Conj` needs to be more polymorphic, possiby Impredicative. I've mucked about trying to give a higher rank type:
>
> ```
> type Conj p q = Prop (forall r.((p -> q -> r) -> r))
> ```
>
> But GHC isn't playing. (And support for Impredicative polymorphism is "flaky".) And a `forall`-quantified thing like that looks suspiciously like the definition for False/uninhabited that I was expecting to use.

I do need a higher-rank type, but not Impredicative. And not on the type for `Conj` but for `commuteAnd`

```
commuteAnd :: (forall r. Conj p q r) -> (Conj q p r')
-- (same function for `commuteAnd` as above)
```

OK. I can happily swap arguments ad infinitum.

**[End of Edit]**

So my question: if it's legit what Newsham is doing with nesting constructors and pattern matching everywhere, then what's not legit about my `IsNat` and pattern matching?

Comment: As Piponi states, the `Proposition` and `Proof` types aren't examples of the Curry-Howard correspondence in action. Those just form a simple LCF-style proof system. The Curry-Howard correspondence is witnessed by the `compile` function (though most of the work is done by `(^)` and `show`) which turns those `Proposition`s and `Proof`s into Haskell code. As for Newsham's code, the wrappers make no difference `(:=>)` is essentially `(->)`. He only adds them (as he explicitly states) so he can swap in a different, non-trivial implementation later on.

Comment: Thanks. wrt Neasham, I wanted to stick with Intuitionistic Logic, not Classical; so ignored the continuations/monad stuff. Are you saying his def'ns don't work for Intuitionistic? Yes `(:=>)` is implemented as `(->)`. But a model/simulation of a logic, needs a validation of the interpreter(?). Why can't I express direct in Haskell `(->)`?

Comment: Similar remarks wrt Piponi: he introduces `(^)` to deal with Classical. OK I'll try his `show` to generate Haskell code and see how that differs. (I'll also try to figure out how he's introducing `Integer`.) I'm trying to use a minimum of Haskell machinery, for fear I'll introduce `_|_` somewhere and undermine "programs are proofs".